# How to Get Primary Key and Unique Constraint Columns in Derby

Tags: derby

How does one do this?  The SYSCOLUMNS system table only has columns for tables.  SYSCHECKS has a REFERENCEDCOLUMNS object.  Is there any way to get this.

I'm aware of the JDBC getPrimaryKeys call, but that doesn't get unique constraint columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Derby - constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845766/derby-constraints)

It took some digging to find the above question; my question is a partially answered follow-up question to the one above.

Taking the CONSTRAINTID against SYSKEYS gives a CONGLOMERATEID, which when taken against SYSCONGLOMERATES yields a DESCRIPTOR.  The DESCRIPTOR is a POJO that contains an int-array in the baseColumnPositions method.  This int-array contains the COLUMNNUMBERS in SYSCOLUMNS of the columns in the constraint.

If querying in straight SQL, getting the DESCRIPTOR field yields a string with a CSV list of ints that have to be parsed.  Fortunately for me, I happen to be working in Clojure, so calling the baseColumnPositions method and using the resulting int-array are trivial.