# How to get a constraint with the column it applies to in Derby database

Tags: constraints, derby

I want to store all constraints of tables in current Derby database,but how to get a constraint with the referenced column?

For example,I have a table named "Customer" with primary key "customer_id", then how could I get the primary key and the column customer_id in case of just know the table name?

Comment: Are you asking how to query the database to learn about the schema dynamically in your program? If so, you should read about the Derby System Catalogs: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefsistabs38369.html or use the java.sql.DatabaseMetaData API.

Comment: I have read those parts and I could only get a constraint and the table it applies to.But I want exactly know which column the constraint applies to.

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845766/derby-constraints or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349785/how-to-get-primary-key-and-unique-constraint-columns-in-derby?rq=1 might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I search the links and it seems that only with the java API supplied by Derby I could get the columns,but how with SQL statements,is this possible?